# Php search form to display similar names?

Tags: php, database, search

Dear Guys i need to know how to create a search form and when a user is searched for a username the username must be displayed with all similar name and all that usernames must be in link form i means if a username is clicked then the user must redirected to mydomain.com/user.php?username= HERE SEARCHED USERNAME

I have the user.php file with user.php?username= USERNAME

I Need to know how to like this page with searched users name in link form.

Comment: A few things...first of all, you haven't indicated in what database you're using (probably MySQL, but you should confirm that). Second, you haven't shown any effort in attempting to solve this problem yourself. It sounds like you want someone to write your code for you. If you don't want to write it yourself, you can hire people to do it for you. But if that's not what you want, then you will have to ask a much more specific question.

Comment: Dude iam beginner to php and i created a basic user control panel and now i created a page called user.php and it will work like mydomain.php?name=USERNAME will show the info about that user and now i have simple search form script and now i need to modify it like when a user search a another user Eg:John then it should show the similar name like John Smith, John Lian, John Badger,John kacks like this and these usernames must be in link format and if the user click on that username it should redirect to user.php?name=ClICKED_USERNAME.
I Just need a an example code

Yes iam using Mysql

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript to accomplish this. It sounds like you are looking for a form with some autocompletion. If you don't know javascript, and don't want to get your hands too dirty, you should take a look at [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [jQuery UI autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

People here on stack overflow will not write your code for you, but that could be a way to get started solving what you are trying to achieve on your own, and learning something in the process :)

Comment: i don't jquery and javascript :( this thing cannot be done just with php functions?

Comment: PHP is a serverside language, and as such cannot do anything dynamic once the client received the content. The only thing the browser can read in relation to functionality (out of the box), is javascript (and to a certain degree html). If you want an easy solution, you could just use a normal `<select name="username" />` in a get form. There is no free text searches here, as the **only** data it can send, is the data you define in your option values.

Comment: can i know how to show a mysql databse info in link format in php?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean. Sorry. If you mean extracting info from a mysql database, and creating a link the user can see and click on, it is too big of a subject to be briefly handed on a forum. There are lots of tutorials on basic database ussage out there, and mysql/php is a very common and potent combo. There is lots of help out there, already written. Seek this out.

Comment: How can i hire a cheap scripter to do this? any website or it's available in stack?